# non-fatal error functionality of Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I was testing the non-fatal error functionality of Crashlytics and can't seem to get the Logs and Keys appear in Crashlytics Dashboard When I called bellow lines in AppDelegate and added logs in one of my ViewController.

let error = NSError(domain:"XYZ", code: Int(1.0), userInfo: nil)
 Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)

But it's working if i add above two lines in my ViewController button Click and add logs in it.. it gives me every log that i added in my application.

But adding in button click seems weird is there any way to do in AppDelegate or any common area?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. This is the order that we process information - crashes, non-fatal exceptions or errors, then at the same level - custom keys, logs and user identifiers. If you capture a custom key or log just before the error then there may not be enough time to write it to disk before we capture the error. Also, one thing to note is that logs and keys are only sent if a crash or non-fatal exception occurs.

Comment: well I understand that .. But how it will get enough time in button click and not enough in ViewDidLoad or AppDelegate method..? the thing is if I don't click that button non of logs will show up in dashboard isn't that a problem here?

Comment: If you add the keys or logs after Fabric has been fully initialized in your app delegate, then the data would be logged. However, it would still only show up if a crash or non-fatal exception happened in the same session.

Comment: I added in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function  after Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) .. like this

Comment: I added in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function after Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) .. like this                     
  CLSLogv("AppDelegate %@", getVaList(["some text"]))
        let error = NSError(domain:"appname", code: 18, userInfo: nil)
        
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error) ...                              but this only gives me the above log not all in my application..

Comment: If it's added after that and the values are not null, then they should show up. If you have a specific link to an issue in Fabric I can dig in more.